# Problem in calling the mask function on jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

My Question is how I'll be to call the jquery function.. Please Check my codes if there's some adjustment..

jquery

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("txtPhone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
});
```

asp.net

```
<script src="insurance.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(function($){
   $('<%=txtPhone.ClientID%>').mask("(999) 999-9999");
});
```

**Edit**

```
jQuery(function($){
       $('.mask').mask("(999) 999-9999");
    });

<asp:TextBox CssClass="mask" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be like this

```
$(function(){
   $('<%= txtPhone.ClientID %>').mask("(999) 999-9999");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using this plug in.

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Change your jquery to have a "#" before the "txtPhone" like this

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#txtPhone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Govind's and Edgar's answers are close because they handle ClientID. This is required if the TextBox is in another container control. However, without the # prefix on the selector, jQuery will try to find all tags with name of "txtPhone" (or the ClientID equivalent). Use selectors like this when you need to get something like all of the div, td, label, etc tags on a page, not when you want to select a tag with the ID value of txtPhone. To use the ID as the selector, you need to prefix the selector with #.

Govind's edit answer works but isn't good for adding a specific mask to a specific control. It would work well if you have a list of controls that need a similar mask. Rather than listing them all by ID in a single selector or using multiple selectors, you can use the class to apply the mask to all controls that need "phone" for example.

Schwechel's answer is the most right but doesn't account for ClientID. The question doesn't specify context to know if ClientID is required, but it doesn't hurt to add it just in case.

Use this code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#<%= txtPhone.ClientID %>').mask("(999) 999-9999");
});
```